# first programm in C-bash: ./: is a directory

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I wrote a short first programme in C in vim.

```
int main() {
        printf("Das ist mein erstes Programm. \n");
        return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with

```
cc -o hello.out hello.c
./ hello.out
```

Yesterday I could see the text "Das ist mein erstes Programm" in my console.

Today I only see:

```
-bash: ./: is a directory
```

I did not change anything in the code. Does anyone know why I got now "is a directory"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You have a space between `./` and `hello.out` - remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with:

```
cc -o hello.out hello.c && ./hello.out
```

You're trying to execute the binary by keeping a space between `./` and `hello.out`:

```
cc -o hello.out hello.c ./ hello.out
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The terminal is interpreting `./` as a directory.

Comment: Thanks it works. But I still don't get it why it worked yesterday the other way and not today.

Comment: @LisanaUchiha it shouldn't have worked. This is not possible.